# Laravel: How to use Sweet Alert 2 instead of Confirmation Message while Deletion?

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, messagebox, sweetalert2

I have Created a Front end Page where user can delete a row from the table. I have added the Confirmation message as:

```
<a rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger btn-link" href="{{action('outboundController@destroy',$row['shipment_id'])}}" onclick = "if (! confirm('Confirm: Press OK to delete the Entry. Shipment ID: {{$row['shipment_id']}}')) { return false; }"style="color: red;">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
```

Now I want to replace the simple confirm message with Sweet Alert 2.
How to do so?

Comment: Do you already check this resource: https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-sweet-alert-example-tutorial/ ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work for me

Comment: which error you get?

Comment: no error, it just doesn't deletes the data, no response

Comment: I think that your action parameter (the second parameter to the given url) is outside an array